# Smooth scrolling with easing isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, easing

I have a `JQuery` function which should allow smooth scrolling with `JQuery` easing however it does not work and I can't seem to find the error.

The code for the function is

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,”) == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,”) && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(‘html,body’).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration:1600,easing:'easeInBounce'});
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/w8zqwn9o/3/) with the function in to give an example. (I included the code for the `JQuery` easing)

Here is a similar function in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/dz9bbouk/8/) however, even though this one does work, it does not include the option to use easing. I would appreciate any help in fixing the problem

**Edit**

To expand on what I mean by it isn't working; there is no animation when the links are clicked, it just instantly scrolls to that spot in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some **very weird** things going on here.

On the following line you are using single double-quotes rather than two single quotes

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,”) == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,”) && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
```

On this line you are using characters that are not single quotes

```
$(‘html,body’).animate()
```

In the end we get this. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhyhjvpb/)

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration:1600,easing:'easeInBounce'});
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

To answer your questions in the comments of this answer, to get the "#" link working we change your `$target =` line to this

```
$target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
```

And to get the anchor to appear on the page we simple remove the `return false;` from the function. After playing with the code I have reduced it to this:

```
$(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1600, easing: 'easeInBounce'});
     });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question do you know why it jumps when top is clicked instead of doing a smooth scroll up and why the link doesn't update? I.e. when orange is clicked the web link doesn't change to `www.mywebsite.com#space-orange`?

Answer (score 0):

I got a probelem with a solution above once I click on link it moves down up before it scroll smoothly. For those who get same problem as mine you can use this version it works better

```
    // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing with other links
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
                }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```